# How to filter logs before write in docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I want to write error logs to GCP. But can't find out how to filter messages with string, ex: `level='error'`

I have read [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/).

Currently, I can't think anyway but write it to Fluentd => filter message => write GCP. But it has added an unnecessary step in my case.

Do we have a straightforward way to filter and send logs directly to GCP?

Comment: Please explain about "But it has added an unnecessary step in my case."  Which unnecessary step ?

Comment: Hi, I want a simple config to filter and send logs directly to GCP.

Comment: I added the tag '[google-cloud-platform]', Chances are higher that someone experienced with that reads this.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way is to just go to [logs explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-interface) and change "severity" to "error" - like so:
[image]

This way you will only see error messages for all your VM's.

It's another matter if you want `fluentd` to send just errors to GCP. In this case you need to reconfigure it. Have a look at the documentation on [how to send structured logs to GCP](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/configuration#structured-records) and make proper changes.

Depending on your needs fist method will work out of the box. Second one needs some tinkering but will also work.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to push all messages to GCP because It is a wasted resource for me. 
 
And currently, I don't want to use Fuentd too - I wrote that in my question.

Comment: You need some software to send logs to GCP, if you don't want to use `fluentd` then you need to write your own piece of code to do the job. Also - it depends which GCP services you want to monitor and collect logs. PLease update your question with more details if possible.